# batch file script moving several objects at once

Tags: batch-file

I am making a pong game, but I ran into a problem trying to make the ball move and letting you move the bar at the same time. This is what I have.

```
set f%p%=%current_pixel%
set g%o%=%pc%
set d%q%=%ball%

cls
```

the code here is listed as `echo %d%` next to d is the number.

```
set d%q%= 
set/a q=%q%+1
if %q%-%p% EQU 9 goto bounce
if %errorlevel% GEQ 1 goto arrow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if %q%-%p% EQU 9 goto bounce
```

This will never be true. `%q%-%p%` would be evaluated to "13-4" for instance, not "9". You need something like

```
set /a r=q-p
if %r% EQU 9 goto bounce
```

It would also help if you were to say what the difficulty was - in this case, the `goto bounce` is never executed even when %q%-%p%=9.

Comment: the ball now will only bounce then come back since the +1 is coming after play.

Comment: The other problem is that I have to move the arrow key in order to move the ball.